# Add PyGUI to project

Tags: python, pycharm, pygui

I am using Windows 7, with [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) (community version!) as an Python editor. I now want to begin using GUI elements for Python. I decided to go with PyGUI...

How can I add it as a library in PyCharm?

Comment: use pip to install it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [this link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pygui/233) for installing this library and then you can check the install status by referring to:

Menu *File* → *Settings* → *Project* → *Project Interpreter*

On this page, you can see a list of installed libraries and you can see the PyGUI library in the list if it is installed.

This library is not found in the regular Python package repositories.